# Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Show that totally disconnectedness and dense in R

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: Give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology. Show that $\mathbb{R}$ has at least two
disjoint totally disconnected subsets, each dense in $\mathbb{R}$.**

This is how I showed it:

Let us consider the sets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ = $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$, then both $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $Y$ be a suspace of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing at least two elements $a$ and $b$ (say). Then, $\exists$ r $\in$ $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$ such that $a < r < b$. Now, $(-\infty, r)$ and $(r, \infty)$ are disjoint open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $Y$ $\cap$ $(-\infty, r)$ and $Y$ $\cap$ $(r, \infty)$ are two non empty disjoint open subsets of $Y$, such that

$Y$ = ($Y$ $\cap$ $(-\infty, r)$) $\cup$ ($Y$ $\cap$ $(r, \infty)$)

Therefore, $Y$ is disconnected. Since, $Y \subset \mathbb{Q}$ is arbitrary, therefore $\mathbb{Q}$ is disconnected. Similarly, we can show that $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$ is totally disconnected. Also, $\mathbb{Q}$ $\cap$ $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$ = $\emptyset$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q^{C}}$are disjoint.

I edited this and found a way to show some parts....

This is what I think it should be, I am not sure. I am not getting the entire part especially showing it properly. Can someone help and guide me on this?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disjoint and dense in $\mathbb{R}$, right?  But now you need to find *another* totally disjoint and dense subset, which is itself disjoint from $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $y$ should be $Y$ for clarity. And the fact that such rational and irrational always exist, is a consequence of their being dense. You might want to make that clear too.

Comment: Done with the 1st one, how to show the 2nd part? i.e. fact that such rational and irrational always exist, is a consequence of their being dense.

Answer (score 1):

Without losing the pedagogical aspect of the question, I am stating two disjoint subsets that obey the conditions mentioned (being a dense set of $\mathbb{R}$ and totally-disconnected): $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.

Unless it is assumed to be known, you can prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ are dense subsets by showing that every real number is the limit of a sequence of points contained in one of the two sets.

For total disconnectedness, it seems to be a simple exercise to prove that the only connected components are the singletons, i.e. any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ with at least two elements is disconnected.

Hope the points raised above help and you can fill the gaps to complete the exercise.

Comment: thanks 4 posting this, I understood it. I have edited the Q with more details. Kindly check and let me know if this looks ok. My prof is very picky when it comes to showing things. You have to show everything properly else he wont let me go. That's why I was thinking of proving this theorem descriptively and I did it, let me know what u think now.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb Q$ is dense and totally disconnected (the proof for the latter is fine). The same proof (mutatis mutandis) will show that $\Bbb P$ (the irrationals) has the same properties. And $$\Bbb R = \Bbb Q \cup \Bbb P$$ and they are by definition disjoint.

Comment: can u pls show them descriptively ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun what do you mean? You do know what the  rationals and the irrationals are, don't you? That's the description, for both of the problems (dense and totaly disconnected).

Comment: @Henno....I have edited the Q with more details. Kindly check and let me know if this looks ok. My prof is very picky when it comes to showing things. You have to show everything properly else he wont let me go. That's why I was thinking of proving this theorem descriptively and hence I asked u to do the same. However, I guess whatever I posted is accurate and correct. If its not, kindly help me out.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I added a few comments.